# Open PDF, save DOCX bugs out after a few dozen documents and outputs garbled/corrupted files

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word, docx

I have a few thousand PDF files that I needs to convert to DOCX. I wrote the following macro:

```
Sub convertPDFtoDOCX()
'
' convertPDFtoDOCX Macro
'
'
    Dim docDirectory As String
    Dim pdfDirectory As String
    Dim docPath As String
    Dim doc As Document

    docDirectory = "C:\Users\<USER>\DOCX\"
    pdfDirectory = "C:\Users\<USER>\PDF\"

    pdfFile = Dir(pdfDirectory & "*.*")

    Do While pdfFile <> ""
        docPath = docDirectory & pdfFile & ".docx"

        Set doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=pdfDirectory & pdfFile)
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=docPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

        Documents.Close
        pdfFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

It works fine for the first few dozen documents, but then starts outputting "corrupted files", that aren't docx and can't be opened with a PDF viewer either. There is no error message when it starts bugging out. The problem doesn't come from the PDF files, since if I stop the macro and start it again on the same documents, they are correctly converted the second time.

"Corrupted" files looks like this:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(fr-FR) /StructTreeRoot 91 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 21/Kids[ 3 0 R 27 0 R 31 0 R 42 0 R 44 0 R 46 0 R 48 0 R 55 0 R 59 0 R 61 0 R 63 0 R 65 0 R 67 0 R 69 0 R 71 0 R 73 0 R 75 0 R 77 0 R 79 0 R 81 0 R 88 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 9 0 R/F3 11 0 R/F4 16 0 R/F5 18 0 R/F6 20 0 R/F7 25 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.2 841.8] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 4428>>
stream
xœ­\Ën7Ýð?Ô.Ý ¨Ä7«‚ ¹%e4ð+²’Y$Yt¤¶£A,9RÛÈüÕ|Æ|ÆìÙäæ^²ÈzðQ-¦ È]U¼$//ï‹¬:<yØÞ¾__o«££Ã“ív}ýóæ¦úþðÅýv{ÿñÇÃ«}Ú¾]¸½[ooïï
```

What causes the issue and how can I fix it?

I use Word 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: Probably Word just doesn't have time to finish saving before the next file. For one thing, don't use Documents.Close - use `doc.Close` - that will be specific to the file you open with `Set doc = ...`  You might also try sticking a DoEvents in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fix the issue without a patch from Microsoft. Meanwhile, you can move your code to run outside Word and create a new Word.Application object for each iteration.